# HTAccess replace string with hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I had a question about a problem I am having with a rewrite rule, I want to make a rewrite rule that gets everything after the hyphen, but it just gets the last word?

**My Link:**

```
http://www.website.com/home/24-nieuws/143-kip-kip-kip-donington.html
```

**I have the following rule:**

```
RewriteRule ^home/24-nieuws/(.*)-(.*).html$  http://www.website.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This rule gives me a weird output, well I find it weird, but It could because a hyphen is used as a regex character?

**Output:**

```
http://www.website.com/donington
```

It skips all of the text and just gets the last word? Does anyone know what I have to do to make it get everything between the first hyphen and the .html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^home/24-nieuws/[^-]*-(.+)\.html$  http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

`[^-]*` is negated character class that match 0 or more non-hyphen characters. It will stop matching before first hyphen.

It is also possible to use a non-greedy quantifier to make it work:

```
RewriteRule ^home/24-nieuws/.*?-(.+)\.html$  http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lhYKyC/1)

Comment: Oh thanks this works perfectly! I didn't know this, but now I do thanks very much! This will be a big help in the future :D